# BlueZ version in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'd like to know a way to know the version of BlueZ (the bluetooth stack) implemented in Android Honeycomb, without having the source code of this system.
I am pretty interested in the HDP functionalities offered by the last versions of this stack.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775414/determining-bluetooth-stack-version-programatically-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Honeycomb released commercially with the SDK in Feb 2011, so I think its safe to say that the BlueZ version is that in use in late-December 2010 or early-January 2011.

Ver. 4.84 released on December 28th, 2010 so I think you will be able to work with that. Hope this helps!

http://www.bluez.org/bluez-484/

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.2(Honeycomb) had been released as the following link. 
  http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/msg/6410b44798c19d61

I had downloaded bluez source code in Honeycomb. It's the early version bluez-4.69 as Android 2.3.
  So, porting bluez is necessary.