# Determining Bluetooth  stack version programatically on an Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

How do I find the [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) stack version on an Android device programatically?

For example, the way to find the Android version is **android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE**. So, is there any similar way to find out the Bluetooth stack version?

Comment: I can't find anything under [android.bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html). Are you sure you need the stack version for your app?

Comment: Yes, I also tried searching but couldn't able to find. I want the bluetooth stack version on a particular android device.

Comment: I tried the following code, but it gives device android version instead of package version: PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.android.bluetooth", 16384); String vc = pi.versionName; Log.d("Version", vc);

Answer (score 1):

```
int version = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
String bluezStack = "";
switch (version) {
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE_1_1:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT:
        bluezStack = "Bluez 3.36";
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_0_1:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO:
        bluezStack = "Bluez 4.47";
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1:
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2:
        bluezStack = "Bluez 4.69";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I presume that there is no way to query bluez stack version from the application directly on a android device.