# Android Bluetooth version and Supported profiles

Tags: android, bluetooth, version, profiles

is it possible to get the android phone Bluetooth version and list of supported Bluetooth profiles.

I saw that we can identify whether the Bluetooth is LowEnergy or not.
Is there any way to find the exact bluetooth version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no API method to get Bluetooth version and Supported profiles from the application directly on a android device, but You can get requirements for version of Android OS from [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd) and get "minimal" BT version and amount of Supported profiles like as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6793973/6950238) answer of [hemisphire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108984/hemisphire) (he analyze SDK Build version):

> ```
> int version = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
> String bluezStack = "";
> switch (version) {
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE_1_1:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT:
>         bluezStack = "Bluez 3.36";
>         break;
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_0_1:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO:
>         bluezStack = "Bluez 4.47";
>         break;
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1:
>     case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2:
>         bluezStack = "Bluez 4.69";
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I am using Marshmallow so 'version' is 23. It is very difficult to get for all devices

Comment: Moreover, on devices of different manufacturers it can work in different ways, but seems, there is no other way.